# Django Static files loading failed

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to load static files in my django project. but it isn't loading. My static folder is in the base directory of project . Here I am giving some relevant code.

Here is my project's settings.py file's static part.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assests')
```

Here is the html part

```
{% load static %}
<img id="undraw_shared_workspace_hwky" src="{% static 'undraw_shared_workspace_hwky.png' %}">
```

My project name is 'webpage' and here is the image path.

```
webpage\static\undraw_shared_workspace_hwky.png
```

I have tried...

```
manage.py collectstatic
```

to collect the static files. It worked and gave me a assests directory inside or root directory.
But when I go to the website it doesn't load the image. and the console says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" .
I am in a windows machine and using Django 3.0.
Now I need you help to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Print `BASE_DIR` to console to check where it points to. If this is not the issue then please show INSTALLED_APPS and urls.py. Alose note, is not "assests", it's "assets".

Comment: What's the generated URL of the image (which you see by means of the dev tools of your browser)? It likely includes some "/assests/undraw_shared_workspace_hwky.png". Thus, you should possibly set your STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR("static")). STATICFILES_DIR specifies a path that you collect static files from. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS for some better wording.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Thanks for your comments. My problem has solved. I have tried to move my static folder and templates folder inside the app and then it ran correctly.

Comment: @rolando Thanks for your comments. My problem has solved. I have tried to move my static folder and templates folder inside the app and then it ran correctly.